# my tkinter doesnt show up anything i have coded

Tags: python, tkinter

i wrote this code, but when i run it it doesnt show any error, but the app is blank can you please show where i have done the mistake. Thank You

```
from tkinter import *
import csv

import os
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Umer Selmani\Desktop\prog.practice\MP1")

root=Tk()
class Diet:
    def __init__(self,Tops,Lefts, Rights):

        self.Tops=Frame(root,width= 200,height=200).pack(side=TOP)

        self.Lefts=Frame(root,width= 200,height=200).pack(side=LEFT)

        self.Rights=Frame(root,width= 200,height=200).pack(side=RIGHT)

        self.label1=Label(Tops,font=("ariel","bold" ,20),text="Sehir Cafeteria",
                          bg="darkblue").grid(row=0,columns=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pass Tops, Lefts & Rights to the `__init__()` function if they are the frames you want to display. They are created in `__init__()`.

The `pack()` function returns `None` which means you don't keep a reference to the respective frames. I have corrected this in my example.

To display the frames defined in the `Diet` class you must first create an instance.

I have color-coded the frames so they are visible.

```
from tkinter import *

class Diet:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Tops = Frame(root, width=400, height=200, bg='tan')
        self.Tops.pack(side=TOP)
        self.Tops.pack_propagate(False)
        self.Lefts = Frame(root, width= 200, height=200, bg='salmon')
        self.Lefts.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.Rights = Frame(root, width= 200, height=200, bg='bisque')
        self.Rights.pack(side=RIGHT)
        self.label1 = Label(self.Tops, font="ariel 20 bold",
                            text="Sehir Cafeteria", bg="darkblue")
        self.label1.pack(fill='x')
        # Grid() will shrink the self.Tops frame to exactly
        # fit the label.

root = Tk()
diet = Diet()   # Create an instance of Diet.

root.mainloop()
```

**Additional explanation**

Different return values from widget creation depending on how the code is written depends on how information is passed between objects:

```
# The first code:
self.Tops = Frame(root, width=400, height=200, bg='tan') 
    # Creates a Frame and associates it with the name "self.Tops"
self.Tops.pack(side=TOP) 
    # uses the geometry manager pack to display the frame "self.Tops" 
    # The method call returns the value: None
    # self.Tops is still referencing the frame

# The second code does the same thing but in a single compound statement
self.Tops = Frame(root, width=400, height=200, bg='tan').pack(side=TOP)
    # Creates a frame and passes a reference to that frame to pack.
    # Pack displays the label on the window and returns the value: None
    # This value is given the reference "self.Tops"
```

Try running the code below and examine the console printout.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

label_a = Label(root, text='A')
return_a = label_a.pack()
print('label_a:', label_a)
print('return_a:', return_a)

label_b = Label(root, text='B').pack()
print('label_b:', label_b)

root.mainloop()
```

Hope this makes things clearer.

Comment: thank you so much, though isnt there anyway that i can fill the top, to be all blue?, should i get rid of that label and use text inside the frame, or is there any other way

Comment: I updated my example. I use `pack_propagate()` to keep the size of the frame and also I set the width to 400. It's easier to use ether pack or grid so I changed the label geometry manager to pack. I'd say that the best way is to sketch the layout on a paper and then decide if pack or grid is better for the layout. Then mark all the elements on the paper before you start coding. When in doubt search SO as there are lots of answers regarding GUI layout.

Comment: and if you have any knowledge about this one please give me and explanation, what is the difference between
self.Tops = Frame(root, width=400, height=200, bg='tan')
self.Tops.pack(side=TOP) and
self.Tops = Frame(root, width=400, height=200, bg='tan').pack(side=TOP),
when i tried to write the code in one line, putting the pack right after, it created the problem of geometry manager. Thank You

Comment: Updated my answer with a further explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do

```
diet = Diet()
diet.pack()
```